# Is there a way to change symbol size units dependent on scale?

Tags: qgis, symbology

Is there a way to change a layers symbol size from paper units(mm) to map units(m) once you hit a certain scale without adding duplicates of each layer?
QGIS 12.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also set the symbol size in map units, then press the "spanner" icon which appears next to the size. This allows you to set either a minimum and maximum size in mm for the symbol, or a scale range to limit the symbol scaling to.

Comment: This works well too...

Answer (score 3):

Rule-based labelling can do it. Define two rules with disjoined scale intervals
and set the other parameters for each rule.

Comment: Thanks! This works great, I tried a whole bunch of different google searches and found nothing helpful. As soon as I put in rule based symbology QGIS I got a myraid of tutorials and help pages. Thanks again.